# LINQ. Request for understanding multiple select and from and where in C#

Tags: c#, linq, select

I'm newish to LINQ and am having trouble with some code I have to read.  I'm not looking for anyone to explain the code to me , rather, I'd like to know:

- First, What are the appropriate search terms for me to learn about this.  I.e. what do you call it when you have multiple Select statement.  My gut feel is that this is an inner join, but I'm not familiar with this LINQ syntax.
- Secondly, Can point me to some references?  I've tried, but I think my inability to come up with the right search terms is limiting me.  I either come up with simple from where select statements, or inner join statements.

Code:

```
var matchingReading = (from myo in _database.SessionDatabaseObject.Nations ?? new List<Nation>()
                               where myo.ReportAbbreviation.ToLower() == nationReportAbbr.ToLower()
                               select (from side in _database.SessionDatabaseObject.Sexes
                                       where sex.Name.ToLower() == sexReportAbbr.ToLower()
                                       select (from recSite in _database.SessionDatabaseObject.RecordingSites
                                               where recSite.NationId == myo.Id
                                               where recSite.SexId == sex.Id
                                               select
                                                   (from harnCh in _database.SessionDatabaseObject.Interviewers
                                                    where harnCh.RecordingSiteId == recSite.Id
                                                    select
                                                        (from reading in
                                                             _database.SessionDatabaseObject.Readings
                                                         where reading.InterviewerId == harnCh.Id
                                                         where reading. RunEventId == _entry.Id
                                                         select reading))))).ToList();
        if (!matchingReading.Any() ||
            !matchingReading.First().Any() ||
            !matchingReading.First().First().Any() ||
            !matchingReading.First().First().First().Any() ||
            !matchingReading.First().First().First().First().Any())
            return "";

        float? height = matchingReading.First().First().First().First().First().Height;
        return height.HasValue ? ((int)Math.Floor(height.Value)).ToString() : "";
```

Comment: These are nested queries. You can find info here: http://www.sql-tutorial.com/sql-nested-queries-sql-tutorial/

Comment: this should be a good start for you http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b

Comment: That query seems to be done by someone that did not know about Linq joins.

Comment: I like all those `First()` calls.  Fun at parties.

Comment: This above example is one reason I hate Linq, and love stored procedures for more complicated queries.

Comment: @Ryk - you hate Linq because someone can write a bad Linq line?  Believe me his Query would have looked just as ugly.

Comment: I'm still confused.  I did check out the links and saw nothing similar.  Is it possible for someone to write a short example of a nested query in standard sql query format?  That might make it more clear.  Is there an implied "in" in front of each "select"? I suspect half my battle is just getting use to the reverse order of select, from, where.

Answer (score 1):

This query is pretty ugly as is, so I exploded it for you. Hopefully this is easier for you to parse:

```
// Find the nations whose name matches nationReportAbbr
// Find the nations whose name matches nationReportAbbr
var matchingNations = _database.SessionDatabaseObject.Nations.Where(nation =>
    String.Equals(nation.ReportAbbreviation, nationReportAbbr, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));
if (matchingNations.Any())
{
    Nation matchingNation = matchingNations.First();

    // Find the sexes whose name matches sexReportAbbr
    var matchingSexes = _database.SessionDatabaseObject.Sexes.Where(sex =>
        String.Equals(sex.Name, sexReportAbbr, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));
    if (matchingSexes.Any())
    {
        Sex matchingSex = matchingSexes.First();

        // Find the recording sites with the appropriate nation and sex
        var matchingRecordingSites = _database.SessionDatabaseObject.RecordingSites.Where(recordingSite =>
            recordingSite.NationId == matchingNation.Id && recordingSite.SexId == matchingSex.Id);
        if (matchingRecordingSites.Any())
        {
            RecordingSite matchingRecordingSite = matchingRecordingSites.First();

            // Find the interviewers with the appropriate recording site
            var matchingInterviewers = _database.SessionDatabaseObject.Interviewers.Where(interviewer =>
                interviewer.RecordingSiteId == matchingRecordingSite.Id);
            if (matchingInterviewers.Any())
            {
                Interviewer matchingInterviewer = matchingInterviewers.First();

                // Find the readings taken by the appropriate interviewer whose RunEventId matches the provided _entry.Id
                var matchingReadings = _database.SessionDatabaseObject.Readings.Where(reading =>
                    reading.InterviewerId == matchingInterviewer.Id
                    && reading.RunEventId == _entry.Id);
                if (matchingReadings.Any())
                {
                    Reading matchingReading = matchingReadings.First();

                    // Find the height
                    float? height = matchingReading.Height;
                    if (height.HasValue)
                    {
                        return ((int)Math.Floor(height.Value)).ToString();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

return String.Empty;
```