# LINQ to SQL QUERY Converter for non-database entities (list, collections, etc.)

Tags: sql, linq

I am trying to make sense of a LINQ query I inherited and am wonder if there are any tools to convert the code to something more sql query like which I might have an easier time understanding.  The LINQ query is not hitting a database but rather collections of POCOs.  So I don't think thinks like DataContext.GetCommand are going to help.  I posted the code in question here:
[LINQ. Request for understanding multiple select and from and where in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17688090/linq-request-for-understanding-multiple-select-and-from-and-where-in-c-sharp)

Basically, I need help translating LINQ syntax to SQL query syntax.

Thanks,

Comment: No, you need help understanding LINQ syntax :-)

Comment: [How to: Display Generated SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386961.aspx)

Comment: [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) might help you make more sense of it... and wow, that's some gnarly LINQ, I'm not sure any tool can help that :P